# Facebook embed posts mobile app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, mobile, swift3

```html
 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
 eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
 minim veniam<p><iframe style=\"border: none; overflow: hidden;\"
 src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpapryka%2Fpost%2F10155342930869898&amp;width=500\"
 scrolling=\"no\" width=\"100%\" height=\"278\"
 frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></p> <p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
 labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
```

I have an app that shows posts from a blog and everything works fine but facebook posts. Wherever the facebook iframe appears i receive information:

```
"This Facebook post is no longer avaliable. It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed."
```

I download content of the post and place it to UiWebView using

```
self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

I placed part of the content string in snippet:

Moreover - i can display facebook videos using that method - it all works. I also tested it on Android - posts and videos works using the content i placed. Any suggestions what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Trying to access https://www.facebook.com/papryka/post/10155342930869898 directly in my browser (desktop) only gives me _“Sorry, this content isn't available right now. The link you followed may have expired, or the page may only be visible to an audience you're not in.”_ - so that does not really seem to be an existing, public post ...

Comment: I refreshed link - it's in the snippet right now - there were some problems with formatting, and i'm sure its existing, public post

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem, all i had to do is pass url to post from blog - embed posts from facebook are displayed correctly now

```
self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: url)
```

Comment: I also had to use a base URL, but also worked for the regular <script> tag version as well.

Answer (score 0):

self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: "https://")

Comment: using "https://" didnt work for me, i had to use a real website url. In my case i went with our companies main page and it worked for me.